# Problem updating UI although correct data in the ngrx payload

Tags: angular, state, ngrx

I have been struggling with updating the UI the last days and I'm not able to find a solution..

**Scenario:** I want to be able to edit a event from event-edit-component, and then be redirected back to the same event in event-detail component when the update is done. I'm able to make the changes in the backend, and the ngrx state shows me the correct data in Redux DevTools. The problem is that when i press update and is redirected to the event-detail, i see the old version of the event, until i refresh the page. Why is everything working like it should only when i press f5?

Thanks..

*Event-detail component (where i should see the updated event)*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation} from 
'@angular/core';

import { AppState } from 'src/app/core/state';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromEvents from '../../state/events';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Event } from 'src/app/shared/models';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertifyService } from 'src/app/core/services/alertify.service';

import * as fromSession from '../../../core/state/session';

@Component({
  selector: 'ex-event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  eventId: any;
  ev$: Observable<Event>;
  eventUsers$: any;
  userId: number;

  constructor(
    private store$: Store<AppState>,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.store$.select(fromSession.selectUser).subscribe(user => (this.userId = user.id));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.eventId = params['id'];
    });
    this.loadEvent();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  loadEvent() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new fromEvents.LoadEvent(+this.eventId));
    this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvents.getCurrentEvent));

    this.eventUsers$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvents.getCurrentUsers));
    console.log(this.ev$);
  }
}
```

*Event-edit component (Where i edit the event)*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from 'src/app/core/state';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Event } from 'src/app/shared/models';
import * as fromEvents from '../../state/events';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ex-event-edit',
  templateUrl: './event-edit.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./event-edit.component.scss']
})
export class EventEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ev$: Observable<Event>;
  eventEditForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvents.getCurrentEvent));

    this.createEventEditForm();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}

  createEventEditForm() {
    this.ev$.subscribe(ev => {
      this.eventEditForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [ev.id],
        title: [ev.title, Validators.required],
        description: [ev.description, Validators.required],
        image: [ev.image],
        location: [ev.location, Validators.required],
        startdate: [ev.startDate],
        starttime: [ev.startDate],
        enddate: [ev.endDate],
        endtime: [ev.endDate]
      });
    });
  }

  updateEvent() {
    if (this.eventEditForm.valid) {

      const ev = Object.assign({}, this.eventEditForm.value);
      this.store$.dispatch(new fromEvents.UpdateEvent(ev));
    }
  }
}
```

*And this is the code for the state*

```
/*--------------UpdateEventActions--------------*/ 

export class UpdateEvent implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT;

  constructor(public payload: Event) {}
}

export class UpdateEventSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT_SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: Update<Event>) {}
}

export class UpdateEventError implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT_ERROR;

  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}


/*--------------UpdateEffect--------------*/ 

@Effect()
  updateEvent$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<eventsActions.UpdateEvent>(eventsActions.ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT),
    map((action: eventsActions.UpdateEvent) => action.payload),
    switchMap((event: Event) =>
      this.eventResource.updateEvent(event).pipe(
        map(
          (updatedEvent: Event) =>
            new eventsActions.UpdateEventSuccess({
              id: updatedEvent.id,
              changes: updatedEvent
            })
        ), 
        tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/event/' + event.id])),
        catchError(err => of(new eventsActions.UpdateEventError(err)))
      )
    )
  );

/*--------------UpdateReducer--------------*/ 
case eventsActions.ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT_SUCCESS: {
      return adapter.updateOne(action.payload, state);
    }

    case eventsActions.ActionTypes.UPDATE_EVENT_ERROR: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      };
    }

/*--------------UpdateSelectors--------------*/ 

import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppState } from '../../../core/state';
import { adapter } from './events.adapter';

const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors();

export const selectState = (state: AppState) => state.event.evs;

export const getEvents = createSelector(selectState, selectAll )

export const getEventsLoading = createSelector(selectState, state => state.loading);

export const getEventsLoaded = createSelector(selectState, state => state.loaded);

export const getError = createSelector(selectState, state => state.error);

export const getCurrentEventId = createSelector(selectState, state => state.selectedEventId);

export const getCurrentEvent = createSelector(selectState, getCurrentEventId, state => state.entities[state.selectedEventId]); //this is the one i use to list the specific event

export const getCurrentUsers = createSelector(selectState, getCurrentEventId, state => state.users);
```

Answer (score 0):

might you provide the code where you change `selectedEventId`?
In the code above I see everything, except the place where the field has been updated and I assume that this can be the answer on your question.